# Checking if polygons are properly adjacent to each other?

Tags: qgis, geometry, qgis-processing, spatial-join, vertices

I have a whole stack of polygons that were supposed to be properly adjacent (vertex to vertex) to each other, but they are not.

Through the process of cleaning this mess, I would like to visualize/run diagnostics to see which edges I haven't fixed yet.

So I wonder what is the simplest way to do this?

I was joining the polygons and checking which failed to merge, but it is a poor practice (one can overlap the border, not match it).

Probably if I create a set of "duplicated" vertices or edges that would be fine, but I didn't find a straight forward way to do that either?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With reference to what you wrote:

> if I create a set of "duplicated" vertices or edges that would be fine

I suggest using vertices instead of edges due to internal coding speeding.

With these premises, this workflow may help (maybe not the fastest solution when dealing with thousand of polygons):

1. extract the vertices from the polygons;
2. perform a spatial join;
3. check the result.

I tested the procedure on these polygons:

[image]

---

### 1) Extract the vertices from the polygons

Run the **Extract nodes** algorithm from the **Processing Toolbox** for both polygons:

[image]

---

### 2) Perform a spatial join

Run the **Join attributes by location** algorithm from the **Processing Toolbox** with these parameters (`layer_1` and `layer_2` are the polygons):

[image]

You will obtain:

[image]

---

### 3) Check the result

Zooming on the result, you will see that an output point was created only when the vertices of both polygons were overlapped:

[image]

This workflow would be a bit annoying if many polygons are involved, but you can easily implementing it using the QGIS **Graphical Modeler**, for instance.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like exactly what I've been looking for - except one detail. All my polygons (~200) are in the same layer.Do I have to put them all as separate layers for that?

Comment: @Philipp_Kats Ah, a misunderstanding: you have 200 **_features_** and 1 **_polygon layer**_. In this case, you may run the **Extract nodes** tool by iterating over the features (you can do this by clicking on the green round arrow on the right of the layer selector): this will produce _n_ point outputs where _n_ is the number of the features involved (~200). Starting from this result, you may apply the spatial join. I don't know any tool which can automatically undestand how your points are snapped with reference to a canonical situation, but the job should be easily done using some python...

Comment: @Philipp_Kats did you read my comment?

Comment: Yeah, thank you a lot! I am leaning towards a python scripting indeed

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it looks like Topology checker plugin can do that:
you can check on the polygons by themselves (do not overlap, do not have gaps) or with the extracted vertices - do not have duplicates (although we actually want duplicates